# Android Floating Action Button comes Up

Tags: android

In my activity when I press on search in action bar, Soft key pad will comes up which is expected but problem is I have one floating action button in bottom which is also coming up as shown below. How to resolve this one.[image]

```
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"  >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        style="?android:attr/listViewWhiteStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/floating_action_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_action_button_height"
         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/floating_action_button_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/floating_action_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_messaging_new_message"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: how is your floating button defined? Show your Layout XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try giving `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"` in your activity tag of your manifest.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution:**

Inside `AndroidManifest` file, your activity tag should look like below to achieve your desired output:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" ... >
```

**Explaination:**

When you use `adjustPan`, the activity's main window is **not** resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

**Reference:** 
[document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: Is there any way so that I can have interactive window and action button invisible when the soft key pad is active.