# I want my FAB to stay at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]I am using the Floating Action Button for my app and have a question on what I am stuck on. It works fine etc but when I click on an EditText in the center of the screen, the keyboard comes but...but so does the FAB. I want it to stay at the bottom of the screen. Is there a way?

```
<FrameLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/title_note_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noteTitle"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Note Title"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/edit_note_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/edit_note_notes"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_note_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Empty"
        android:id="@+id/edit_note"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="start"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/menuicon" />
```

Comment: </FrameLayout> is at the end. Just wouldn't come up.

Comment: If you're asking whether your FAB can float over the keyboard (Z axis), blocking some of the keys, then no, that's not how it works. You might wish to consider uploading a screenshot somewhere and using it to explain in greater detail what you're seeing and what you're wanting.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! In the process now in trying to add my image :). Should be up in a second :)

Comment: @CommonsWare Just added the Edit and screenshot :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Floating Action Button comes Up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774323/android-floating-action-button-comes-up)

Comment: The amount of search's and variations for what I was looking for never seem to find me what I want :(. Thanks @Mdlc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practice is to hide the FAB when the soft keyboard comes up.

Please add:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

to the corresponding activity in your AndroidManifest.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much :). Its what I needed :). I found out there is another question like this but you answered for me :). Thanks again!